# Динамическая вставка видео по ссылке

Tags: php, youtube

Хочу реализовать такую функцию на сайте: пользователь вставляет в поле ссылку на YouTube-видео и отправляет форму. Необходимо из ссылки получить код видео и вставить на сайт. Частенько вижу такую функцию на разных сайтах.

Если есть предложения, ссылки и т.д. — был бы признателен. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Видео YouTube характеризуется 11-значным цифробуквенным кодом (xxxxxxxxxxx). Поэтому нужно следующее.

Получить код (или ссылку с кодом, а потом вырезать код из ссылки регулярным выражением)

```
<?php
    preg_match(
        '/[\\?\\&]v=([^\\?\\&]+)/',
        'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxxxxxxx&feature=channel',
        $matches
    );
?>
```

Вставить на страницу объект, содержащий ссылку на код

```
<object 
    data="http://www.youtube.com/v/xxxxxxxxxxx" 
    type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
        <param name="src" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/xxxxxxxxxxx" />
</object>
```